# Detect when play button clicked in the video of my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I"m developing a website for children. here i'm viewing videos for children.i want to handle some procedures when child click the play button.how can i catch that event when child press the play button. (I'm using html  tag to play videos).Someone please help me. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('play', 'video', function(){
  //do something
});
```

Events https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html